# Accidental Flagging on Android App

Tags: feature-request, flags, android-app

When flagging a question, while on a web browser, I always find myself reading the description of the categories in which I consider the question may fall into, until I settle on the correct one. Very frequently I end up backtracking through the tree of possible options searching for the right one as I don't want to penalize a person asking a question for the incorrect motives. This all works just fine as the website only accepts my decision until I explicitly click the right corner blue button. (
Picture below)

[image: Flagging on a Web Browser]

Now, when I'm browsing SO on the Android app things are less safee. Whenever I consider a question for flagging, a Popup shows up with the possible questions, but no 'are you sure' mechanism. (Picture below)

[image]

Without an 'are you sure' mechanism, once a category is selected, the flag is automatically submitted. The pop-up UI doesn't make it clear to the user that clicking an option means an immediate submition without the possibility of undoing it. So because one cannot confirm the decision, it opens up the possibility of submitting unintended flags. I guess this would make the user flagging the question untrustworthy, but more importantly, it wastes the reviewers time.

So, what I would like to propose as a functionality for the Android app, is some mechanism that allows the users confirm a flag before it is submitted. =)

(Also, there is no convenient way to go back through the tree of flagging options, but that problem isn't as important as mis-flagging a question.)

Comment: It is already 3 step action, I don't think it is good idea to add another step.

Comment: Thats true, usually there more steps, the less usable becomes something, but there are cases were a confirmation becomes important as the data being submitted is not to be taken lightly.

Comment: I don't think raising invalid flag by mistake could be fatal, because anyway flags are being reviewed and will be probably declined if you raised it by mistake.

Comment: @gevorg: too many declined flags can lead to not being able to flag at all. In addition, some flags lead to community review of the flag, and the community is, um...less than perfect about reviewing flagged posts. As far as the number of steps go, this request is (essentially) asking for the mobile version to have the same number of steps as the desktop version. If the steps are not too many for the desktop scenario (and I don't think they are), they should also not be too many for the mobile side.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, I know, I just had a situation when I was not able to flag during 7 days. My understanding was that cavpoll complains about accidents...one or two cases from many others, that cannot cause ban if  other flags are fine. Agree, community is not perfect (just the fact that it includes me, already proves it :D), but it is the base for everything here in SE/SO. I got your point, but I don't think adding another step is good option from UX perspective and I would prefer to have accidental wrong flags instead.

Comment: @gevorg: _"I would prefer to have accidental wrong flags instead"_ -- you're welcome to your opinion. Just be aware that that opinion goes against fundamental user-interface guidelines. Accidental irrevocable actions which can have harmful consequences warrant at least two-step approval from the user, no matter how many steps it took the user to reach the point of initial confirmation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well, I think there are two important things from user-interface perspective, 1. more steps cause more complexity and that causes less usage, 2. number of steps for action should be directly proportional to danger of raising flag by mistake, which in this case is not a big deal as community reviews your flags.

Comment: **Suggestion:** A double tap may be the solution, First Tap selects the category and second Tap submits the flag.

Comment: If the number of steps is the concern, why don't we apply the same as most apps do, you keep the same steps, but once flagged there is a temporary popup/thingy that allows you to "undo" the decision. I personally prefer "undo when necessary" above "always have to confirm".

Comment: Also, I've been thinking, making more than 75% of a touch screen a *submit button* seems to me like a dangerously-prone-to-mistakes-UI. (Whereas on the website, we have a tiny button that takes less than 5% of our click area)

Comment: @g00glen00b Yep, just do it completely on the UI side, no API changes necessary. Pretend to send the flag ASAP, but keep the toast, and only send on timeout. If the toast is canceled, don't.